# Obtaining a Time Zone Locale that is Different from Local Machine

Tags: java, python, date, datetime, timezone

I am writing a method that would return a time zone i.e. UTC timezone with different date. This method should take time zone that user has set as an input. I understand that I would have to cross the International Date Line to go to the timezone with different date, but I am not sure if I am missing something here. 
e.g. If I am in EST timezone, return timezone where date is different from EST timezone.

```
public String getDifferentDate (String timeZone) {
    //Calculate the time zone offset required to cross International Date line
    //RETURN newTimeZone with different date.
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should add some code showing us what you did try and explain a little more what you actually want.

Comment: Which language? Java or Python?

Comment: language does not matter. Java or Python both works

Comment: There are multiple timezone where date is different. Which one should be returned?

Comment: Any! The purpose here is to get the timezone with different date! If there are multiple timezones, then return the one where the change of date appears first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get some timezone where the date is different from the current date in the given timezone:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import datetime
import pytz # $ pip install pytz

def get_timezone_with_different_date(input_timezone_id, now=None):
    """
    input_timezone_id: the tz database id such as 'America/New_York'
    now: a naive datetime object representing time in input_timezone_id
    """
    input_tz = pytz.timezone(input_timezone_id)
    if now is None:
       now = datetime.now(input_tz) # use the current time
    else: 
       now = input_tz.localize(now, is_dst=None) # make it timezone-aware

    for tz in map(pytz.timezone, pytz.all_timezones_set):
        if tz.normalize(now.astimezone(tz)).date() != now.date():
             return tz.zone
    assert 0, 'never happens'
```

Example:

```
>>> get_timezone_with_different_date('US/Eastern')
'Australia/Melbourne'
```

Note: In general, you don't need to cross the International Date Line to get a different date.

Comment: Really appreciate your time J.F. Sebastian. How would we do this in Java?

Comment: @user3001378: you could implement the same algorithm using [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or a similar library in Java.